# Oracle PL/SQL to Load XML

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I don't know the best way to ask this, but let me explain the issue and it may help.

We currently have a feed of data that is distributed to us using an Oracle OAI hub. The data is fed to us using DBLinks.

The information provider is going to be upgrading to Oracle ODI, and for numerous reasons are mandating that all data transfer is conducted using encrypted XML files over SFTP.

Now this introduces a new issue for ourselves as data recipient, as we now need to amend our systems to load XML data into the tables that once were populated by DBLinks.

The set-up we currently have is:

- Oracle 10g (10.2.0.4)

  - Oracle is running on Unix (HP-UX)
- Numerous Win2k3 servers controlling interface / ETL flow.

So currently, the OAI hub will place data into a number of tables in our ETL layer. Say for example "PERSON". The structure of this table i dont believe is relevant...

When the data has been loaded into the PERSON table, the OAI delivery will transmit an End-of-file marker to the database, this is stored in table "EOF" - it holds a count of recieved records expected in "PERSON".

The windows server has a batch process that polls every 30 seconds, this checks to see if an EOF record exists, if it does then it kicks off our ETL processing.

I want to avoid changing this part of the system if possible, so what i am proposing as a solution is to parse the new XML files and load them into the Oracle database, the question is what is the best way to do this:

- The XML files will be delivered to the Windows Servers
- Preference would be to use PL/SQL to load the data

What is the best way to load the data into the Oracle (Unix) database, with the source data being on the Windows side.

I want to avoid having to use any Unix scripting if possible - as my development team don't have enough Unix experience to let them loose on this.

Any suggestions will be grateful.

The XML format is as below - and element names map to column names on DB:

```
<PERSON>
  <HEADER>
    <Creator>~</Creator>
    <DigitalSigniture>~</DigitalSigniture>
    <Owner>~</Owner>
    <Title>~</Title>
    <Marking>~</Marking>
   </HEADER>

   <PERSONS>
     <EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>~</EMPLOYEE_NUMBER>
     <FIRST_NAME>~</FIRST_NAME>
     <LAST_NAME>~</LAST_NAME>
     ......
   </PERSONS>
<PERSON>
```

EDIT:
I am also conscious of volumes, on a normal (average) day i will be processing about 80,000 XML records, and on an exceptional day i will processing up to 300,000 (typically once per year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shred your XML and load them into Oracle-tables, you can use the technique I described in this blogpost: http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2010/03/shredding-xml-into-multiple-tables-in.html

Regards,
Rob.

Some links for loading the files:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb25loa.htm#ADXDB2900
http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=416

Comment: I dont think thats really what i am trying to achieve. For each table i want to load i am going to have a new XML file.

One thing i am concerned about is volumes, on a good day i will be processing about 80,000 records, on a heavy day around 300,000.

Comment: So a single XML file corresponds one-on-one to a single relational table? If so, you are even luckier as you can do a single "INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM XMLTABLE(...)". Or am I still missing something? And for those volumes, you'll definitely want to look at a single SQL statement, instead of doing PL/SQL processing...

Comment: Thats correct, i think my issue is more - how to get the source data (from windows) into the database in the first instance (unix).... unless i can do this using SQL run from the Windows box?

Comment: How about something like just pushing the source XML into a new table that just has a key and a CLOB column, using SQL*Loader or perhaps external tables. And then shredding that, as Rob suggests, into your relational tables.

Comment: @Jim: I have just added some links to my answer that are exactly about that

Comment: @Rob although i don't think this solves my problem directly, it has given be some "food for thought" thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer to forget about build-in Oracle XML features and use any normal language to process XML files on the "client side" and submit ready to use data to the DB. (Look for Python or .NET)

It could be a security risk, if you allows to access DB server file system from network.

80 000 records a day should not be a big problem for Oracle. We do much more close to real time.

Comment: That's also possible, but since he has a development team with PL/SQL skills, I think using Oracle XML features will be most familiar to them. By the way, I loved your "any normal language" phrase, though :-)

Comment: Yeh this is where i was thinking, i have a few Java devs at my disposal, .NET is an issue due to the restrictive environments i am working on.

Comment: I'm developing quite big system, that we use internally in our company. The most of the business logic is in PL/SQL code. So I could say, that I'm an PL/SQL developer. At the same time all front-end and data import is vb.net( main advance that it is nicely integrated with Excel, that we use as a "browser" from our data) I would recommend Python to process data. Simple language and really easy to use with SQL queries. I made a simple test: upload quite some data to the DB. Results were much better than using our "standard" way with .NET.